# How can I throw an exception out of an AJAX call and out of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, scope

Say if I have this jQuery AJAX call within a function:

```
function callPageMethod(methodName, parameters) {
    var pagePath = window.location.href;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pagePath + "/" + methodName,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: parameters,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("ajax successful!");
        },
        error: function (response) {

            // this line is not working!
            throw response.responseText;
        }
    });
} // end of function
```

...I am getting this error in Visual Studio 2010:

> `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught`.

It seems as if this problem is not related to Visual Studio though, but is particular to javascript.

For example, I can declare a variable in this function before the `$.ajax` call, assign it in `error:`, and then `throw` it out of the function *after* the `$.ajax` call with no problems...

So how can I throw an error out of a nested function in this way? I want to `catch` this error outside of this function if possible.

Comment: You wont be able to catch it outside of the function - ajax is asynchronous. Just return the result of the ajax call (a jQuery deferred object), and take advantage of jQuery's deferred methods

Comment: Sometimes a security error from an _XMLHttpRequest_ will dodge error handlers on that request/in surrounding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here are some possible solutions to this I have found:

---

1 -- assign a variable with the `error` value, and throw it after the
    `$.ajax` call:

```
function callPageMethod(methodName, parameters) {
    var errorValue = null;

    $.ajax({
        ...
        ...
        ...
        error: function (response) {
            errorValue = response.responseText;
        }
    });

    if (errorValue != null) {
        throw errorValue;
    }
}
```

2 -- make the `$.ajax` call *synchronous*:

```
function callPageMethod(methodName, parameters) {
    var errorValue = null;

    $.ajax({
        ...
        ...
        ...
        async: false,
        error: function (response) {

            // now it works:
            throw response.responseText;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: solution 2 is not working anymore, I get a uncaught error